# Disable tsserver for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

While editing a React project in Visual Studio Code (1.28.2, Mac OS 10.14, all extensions disabled), the entire system often slows to a crawl. It's not clear what triggers this, but it's seems to be just normal text editing.

Usually when I look in VSCode's Process Explorer, the `electron_node tsserver.js` process is using the most CPU.

Is it possible to disable whatever it is that makes this process run? I don't mind losing features; I just want to be able to edit files.

Comment: Hey, you should file an issue about that: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new?template=bug_report.md

Comment: @MattBierner I filed [61411](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/61411). But it's hard to reproduce.

Comment: I'm using vscode with ssh to access raspberry pi and the tsserver kept freezing the raspberry pi.

Comment: I found  cpulimit for linux,  highly recommended, cpulimit -p 28344-l 20 . Hope some alternative faster language server would emerge.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Disable the "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features" built-in extension to Visual Studio Code (for your current workspace or globally, as you desire).  You can find this extension by going to the extension manager, selecting "Show Built-in Extensions" from the "..." menu, and looking in the "Features" section.

Comment: How can I disable it for an specific project?

Comment: Disabling that took away whole auto-completion, auto-import features..

Comment: @İlker that's a good thing, because disabling auto-completion and auto-import decreases file and cpu usage.

Comment: In my VScode I cannot select "Show Built-in" but I can use "@builtin TypeScript" in the search bar of Extensions and it responds.

Answer (score 9):

I have the problem when updating npm packages while VSCode is open.

For me this works: By turning on the setting `typescript.disableAutomaticTypeAcquisition` tsserver.js can be tamed and CPU usage drops to 0% almost immediately.

Comment: Oh please tell me, how do you do that?

Comment: .vscode -> settings.json -> {"typescript.disableAutomaticTypeAcquisition": true}